# How do I get my magnetrons to auto attack?

Tags: command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge

I see many videos of competitive players who magnetrons appear to auto attack enemy tanks. However, I've never been able to do this and have to manually click each enemy tank one by one. I've tried tricks such as enabling guard mode as well but doesn't seem to work.

How do I get my magnetrons to auto attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally discovered that I just need to hold CTRL+SHIFT and attack the area you want them to move to. They will automatically lift enemy tanks.